# How can convert to only first uppercase letter and other letters lower case in P/L SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have uppercase word like (NO, YES, FAIL) these word in database column i need to select these column value as No, Yes, Fail(only fist letter uppercase and other letters are lowercase)

is there any in-build function in p/l sql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [InitCap](http://psoug.org/snippet/InitCap_188.htm).

```
SELECT InitCap( your_column )
  FROM your_table
```